# Consumer is not authorized to access %resources self

Tags: magento2

I am bulding a mobile app and I know there are a lot of these questions and I went trough them all, but i still got this problem (Using Magento 2.2.2). I tried with curl, postman, hurl.it and i get this message

> message : "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources" parameters
>   : {resources: "self"}

This is my request (Postman)

```
GET /rest/V1/customers/me HTTP/1.1
Host: myshop.dev
Authorization: Bearer grw5y9b3se261541evcdl1js8jd27c8f
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**What i did so far:**

- I did put space on `Bearer grw5y9b3se261541evcdl1js8jd27c8f`
- Checked everything multiple times (letter by letter)

**Further explanation:**

This is a new installation of Magento with sample data. 
I have read the documentation here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html , and i am doing it using *Customer access tokens*. (Since i am doing a mobile app i chose this way) I also registered/created a customer and with his email / password i am doing the following:

(Curl example)

> curl -X POST "http://myshop.dev/rest/V1/integration/customer/token" 
>        -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
>        -d "{"username":"customer1@example.com", "password":"customer1pw"}"

and that returns me token, with it i am trying to do a request (see Postman request) to see user data, but with no success. Am i missing something here? Something in apache, php? or am i doing something wrong.

**EDIT**

Since nothing worked I deleted Magento and did a fresh installation again, and now it works, I didn't do anything different than before, and that is very confusing.

Comment: Are you sure that user have role with access to this resource??

Comment: I created this customer and i am using his data to get customer token ( If i figured out correctly ) then to get his data. I didn't add / change any roles, as i taught it was not necessary ( Since documentations didn't mention to do that for Customer access tokens, only for Integration token type)

Comment: ahh  didnt notice there is `customers/me` . My mistake, sorry. I will post answer

Comment: What is your exact Magento 2 version?

Comment: My version is 2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below two options in different M2 versions:

- After login in Customer Account, tried to access `http://<hostname>/rest/V1/customers/me` Rest API with session based access.
- Using Customer token tried to access `V1/customers/me` Rest API using Advanced Rest Client

In Magento version 2.1.6 both above options worked fine.

In Magento version 2.2.2, I was getting `Consumer is not authorized` error in first option but able to get the customer info from second info.

Comment: I was able to get it working with new a installation. Really strange, didn't do nothing different than before with version 2.2.2.

Comment: can you give me details on your server configuration (Php version, Database...). So i can compare to mine, i am wondering why it is working now (since i have no clue to why it is working now on version 2.2.2 )?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and finally found the solution [here](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/magento-error-the-consumer-isnt-authorized-to-access-resources-in-rest-api-using-postman/).

Turns out the issue was Postman - I had to delete the cookies that Postman automatically attaches to requests. Once I deleted all cookies for my site I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

the admin token is not required. The route `rest/V1/customers/me` can be used by a logged in user without a token to return information about that customer. Please try the following:

- Go to storefront in browser
- Create user account
- Login to user account
- Enter URL `http://<hostname>/rest/V1/customers/me`, replacing  with the server you are using

This will return information about the logged in customer directly to your browser.
If you want to get information about any other customer, you will need to generate an admin token and use it with the route GET `/V1/customers/{customerId}`

EDIT:
Have You tried this: [CLICK HERE](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/REST-API-call-to-get-logged-in-customer-ID/m-p/62092#M1813)    ?
It should be helpful :)

Comment: I tried exactly this before and i was  getting the same error in browser. So there must be an error somewhere else?

Comment: I just edit my post

Comment: I will be building an mobile app, so that is the reason i chose this way. I will try this too. Just to see if i can get the user info and not the error

Comment: I solved this by "reinstalling" magento, fresh install and now it worked. The funny part is i didn't do anything different than the first time.